# Не получается создать по отдельности папку и файл

Tags: flutter, dart

main_page.dart

```
import '../storage.dart'

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget { 
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _createListsFolder('tempList');
    // _createListFile('words');
    _createFile('tempList', 'words');
  }
...
...
  Future<void> _createListsFolder(String folderName) async {
    await storage.createListsFolder(folderName);
  }

  Future<void> _createListFile(String fileName) async {
    await storage.createListFile(fileName);
  }

  Future<void> _createFile(String folderName, String fileName) async {
    await _createListsFolder(folderName);
    await _createListFile(fileName);
  }
...
...
}
```

first_page.dart

```
import '../storage.dart'

class OpenCards extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OpenCardsState createState() => _OpenCardsState();
}

class _OpenCardsState extends State<OpenCards> {
...
...
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _writeData(_words);
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  Future<void> _writeData(List<List<dynamic>> data) async {
    await storage.writeData(data);
  }
...
...
}
```

storage.dart

```
final Storage storage = Storage();

class Storage {
  String listFolder;
  String listFile;
...
...
  Future<String> get localPathDBs async {
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<String> createListsFolder(String folderName) async {
    final _localPathDBs = await localPathDBs;
    Directory listsFolderPath =
        await Directory('$_localPathDBs/$folderName').create();

    return listFolder = listsFolderPath.path;
  }

  Future<String> createListFile(String fileName) async {
    File listsFilePath =
        await File('$listFolder/$fileName').create(recursive: true);

    return listFile = listsFilePath.path;
  }

  Future<void> writeData(List<List<dynamic>> data) async {
    await File(listFile).writeAsString(data, mode: FileMode.write);
  }
...
...  
}
```

В файле *main_page.dart* создаю сразу папку и файл.
В файле *first_page.dart* при закрытии страницы сохраняю данные в созданный файл.
Программа создает/сохраняет, но у меня два вопроса.
Правильно ли сделал, что создал экземпляр **storage** в файле *storage.dart* и через него создавал директорию/файл и сохранял данные. Или это не так делается?
И второй вопрос. При создании файла мне приходится работать через метод **_createFile**. То есть, в параметрах передавать и имя директории и файла. По одельности (сначала создать директорию, затем файл - закоментированные строки в *main_page.dart*) не получается. Вот такая инфа в консоли отладки:
*I/flutter ( 5560): ===== directory: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.eng_translator/files/tempListsDict1
E/flutter ( 5560): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'null' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)*.
Наверное, это связано с Future. Решить эту проблему не смог. Только так, как сделал. Возможно ли отдельно создать папку и файл?

Comment: 1) Делать глобальный инстанс не очень хорошо, как в плане оптимизации, так и в плане написания хорошего кода. Его следует создавать внутри класса где он используется. Либо если вам нужен единственный объект, использовать `singleton`, `ioc` или `service locator`. 2) Да из-за асинхронности, у вас файл начинает создаваться быстрее папки. В `initState` `async` использовать нельзя, по этому остается использовать только `then()` у `Future`. Либо отделять логику от ui (`Bloc`, `Redux`, `MobX`).

Answer (score 0):

*Перенос ответа из комментариев, чтобы закрыть вопрос.*

Делать глобальный инстанс не очень хорошо, как в плане оптимизации, так и в плане написания хорошего кода. Его следует создавать внутри класса где он используется. Либо если вам нужен единственный объект, использовать `singleton`, `ioc` или `service locator`.

Из-за асинхронности, у вас файл начинает создаваться быстрее папки. В `initState` `async` использовать нельзя, по этому остается использовать только `then()` у `Future`. Либо отделять логику от `ui` (`Bloc, Redux, MobX`)